# Media queries on Kindle Fire landscape mode vs. iPad query in landscape mode

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, media-queries, kindle

I'm new to web development and responsive design, so this might be an idiotic question. Unfortunately, I have searched and searched and cannot find an answer.

When I write a media query for Kindle Fire landscape, it effects the iPad landscape and vice versa. I cannot separate them. I have tried many things and nothing works.I don't have a problem in portrait mode or with other devices. I assume this is a problem here because the resolutions overlap, but I thought the code below would make them mutually exclusive. It doesn't.

Kindle landscape

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1024px){ #help{color: red;}}

iPad landscape

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){/*default color is white for desktop version so I don't specify the color in this query*/ }}

The code above will make iPad #help red. If I reverse the order and put iPad first and Kindle second, then #help is white in Kindle.

And this code below makes the iPad landscape look fine, but Kindle is all broken.

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){ /*code*/;}}

What am I doing wrong??? How do I write code so that I can make my website look right on Kindle without messing up the iPad? Do I need something else, like javascript?